# Dealing with an IOError by skipping the current loop iteration

Tags: python

My code structure is laid out like this (simplified):

```
while self.flag == True:
    function1()
    function2()
    function3()
    function4()
    self.emit(...)
```

Sometimes due to hardware issues, I happen to get IOErrors - not a big deal, all I have to do is manually restart this loop but I want the program to just keep going with the program when an error happens.

I know about

```
try:
    <something>
except IOError:
    <something>
```

In this case

```
try:
    <my loop>
except IOerror:
    pass
```

could work. But I'm not too sure about this implementation because if there is an error say in the middle of function2. I do not want function3() or function4() to run at all. I want the program to skip back to function1() and disregard the rest of the loop.

As far as I know, pass just does nothing, and allows the program to continue. Due to my application, if there is an IOError, I know for sure the output of my functions will be corrupt so I just need it to skip the current loop iteration altogether.

How can I do this?

Comment: just put the `try` inside the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to skip current iteration and try again, don't put the whole `loop` inside `try`, put `try` inside your `loop`:

```
while self.flag == True:
    try:
        function1()
        function2()
        function3()
        function4()
        self.emit(...)
    except IOError as e:
        // handle your error here
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the `try: except:` in the loop, for example:

```
while self.flag:
    try:
        function1()
        function2()
        function3()
        function4()
        self.emit(...)
    except IOError:
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

If this becomes common, I would wrap it up into context manager:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def ignoring(exception):
    try:
        yield
    except exception:
        pass
```

Then you can use this wherever you want to ignore exceptions:

```
while self.flag:
    with ignoring(IOError):
        function1()
        function2()
        function3()
        function4()
        self.emit(...)
```

I would also gather the functions into a single function:

```
def process(self):
    function1()
    function2()
    function3()
    function4()
    self.emit(...)
```

Then you're left with:

```
while self.flag:
    with ignoring(IOError):
        self.process()
```

which I find quite readable.